# URI Mapper with query string doesn't seem to work

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, query-string, uri

I'm attempting to set up a URI mapper so that in the end, I can pass a query string to the xaml page I am loading.

Here's what I have defined in the XAML.

```
<navigation:Frame.UriMapper>
    <uriMapper:UriMapper>
         <uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="RequirementOverview/{id}" MappedUri="/View/Pages/RequirementOverview.xaml?id={id}" />
         <uriMapper:UriMapping Uri="/{pageName}" MappedUri="/View/Pages/{pageName}.xaml"/>
    </uriMapper:UriMapper>
</navigation:Frame.UriMapper>
```

My Intention is that if you click on a link such as '/RequirementOverview/Foo' "Foo" is passed as a query string to the Requirement page, and then we can do our magic with it.

However when calling Fame.Navigate("RequirementOverview/Foo", UriKind.Relative) I always end up at the page like thus: hostpage.aspx#/RequirementOverview/Foo and no query is passed to the page.  Rather, it seems to work (the navigation), but my navigationContext queryString comes back null.

Is my approach for this incorrect?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm wondering if you need to remove the last / in "Frame.Navigate("RequirementOverview/Foo", UriKind.Relative)". Everything else looks right to me.

Comment: Ah, that last slash was accidental, I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The URL that you get in the bowser (hostpage.aspx#/RequirementOverview/Foo) is what you should expect since you're using mapped URIs.

To get the `QueryString` parameters, all you have to do is override the `OnNavigatedTo` of your page, access the `QueryString` (which is a `Dictionary<string,string>`) property of the `NavigationContext` which is a member of the `Page` class, like this:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
       var id = int.Parse(NavigationContext.QueryString["id"];
    }
    catch{}
}
```

Hope this helps :)