# Navigation page with parameters

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, url-parameters

I'm trying to pass a parameters in my navigation page, in silverlight, but this doesn't work.

I got the error : `No xaml found at /Views/post`while I have in my adresse bar  : `/Views/post?id=53`

Here is the part in my mainPage.xaml :

```
<Border BorderBrush="Black"
        BorderThickness="0.5"
        Background="Beige"
        Opacity="0.70" 
        Visibility="Collapsed"
        CornerRadius="5">
    <HyperlinkButton x:Name="Link4" 
                    Style="{StaticResource LinkStyle}" 
                    NavigateUri="/post?id={id}" 
                    TargetName="ContentFrame" />
</Border>
```

So, I tried load directly my page like this, when I 'm logged :

```
ContentFrame.Navigate(new Uri("/post?id=53", UriKind.Relative));
```

But when I arrived in my page (type Navigation.Page), I don't succes at get the `53` in parameters, when I go in my constructor :

I tried this :

```
string id = this.NavigationContext.QueryString["id"];
```

But NavigationContext is null

Also tried this :

```
    Uri uri = new Uri(Application.Current.Host.Source.AbsoluteUri);
```

Nothing useful in it.

I never pass parameters in url in silverlight. How can I resolve this?

Plus, when I wrote directly the url in the adresse bar, it seems that, this is not always works.

Answer (score 3):

Think you need override OnNavigatedTo method where you can get NavigationContext instance.

Example:

```
// Executes when the user navigates to this page.
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    this.Init(NavigationContext.QueryString["id"], NavigationContext.QueryString["id"]);
}
```

Also, i think you need implement a UriMapper in a Frame, then you can get desired parameters.

Example:

```
<navigation:Frame x:Name="NavigationFrame" Navigating="NavigationFrame_OnNavigating">
  <navigation:Frame.UriMapper>
    <uriMapper:UriMapper>
      <uriMapper:UriMapping MappedUri="/Views/Page.xaml?id={id}" Uri="/Page/{id}" />
    </uriMapper:UriMapper>
  </navigation:Frame.UriMapper>
</navigation:Frame>
```

Comment: can't get NavigationContext instance in constructor. It equals null.

Page.OnNavigatedTo method's description: "Called when a page becomes the active page in a frame". 
It took from msdn. Think, it's better place for processing NavigationContext.

Comment: Still, I don't always can go in my page when I enter the adress.

Comment: Did u try to get NavigationContext in OnNavigatedTo method? What is the value of NavigationContext?

Comment: Take a look for similar questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4555985/how-can-i-pass-query-string-variables-with-navigationservice-navigate
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6831126/uri-mapper-with-query-string-doesnt-seem-to-work

Comment: i got the value in the navigation context, but only when I go in the page. The problem is, I don't always going through it. About half time, when I enter the adresse, nothing happened.

Comment: Can't you load a page when you enter address?

Comment: Not always. That's why it's weird.

Comment: It's another question.